# Casting a list of list into a NumPy: understanding the resulting shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How comes

```
np.array([[1],[2],[3,4]], dtype=object).shape
>> (3L,)
```

while

```
np.array([[1],[2],[3]], dtype=object).shape
>> (3L, 1L)
```

?

Why `[[1],[2],[3,4]]` doesn't yield the same shape as `[[1],[2],[3]]`, when cast into a NumPy array?

Comment: Numpy doesn't allow "ragged" arrays.  The data in the second example can be organized into a 2-d array with shape (3, 1), so numpy makes it a 2-d array of python integers.  The data in the first example can not be organized as a 2-d array, so numpy does the best it can by making it a 1-d array of python lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second case will be compatible with a 2d numpy `ndarray`: it is a list of lists, and the second level has the same lengths all around. This is why you get a 2d shape (a column vector, to be precise). The first case, on the other hand, has incompatible lengths, and you can only construct a 1d, <strike>array</strike>-* list-valued `ndarray` from that.

Check the arrays themselves:

```
a = np.array([[1],[2],[3,4]], dtype=object)
b = np.array([[1],[2],[3]], dtype=object)
```

```
In [1482]: a[2]
Out[1482]: [3, 4]

In [1483]: b[2,0]
Out[1483]: 3
```

*thanks to [@Warren Weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser) for the clarification